¿Cómo se puede cambiar el tamaño de un vector ya inicializado (JAVA)?
Tengo que modificar el vectorTarea y devolverlo en el procedimiento de añadir(tarea), no puedo crear otro vector, ya que tiene que ser vectorTarea 100% para que la clase siga funcionado. En añadir(tarea), el vectorTarea actualmente me dará un problema de tamaño, ya que obviamente no podría realizarlo en el intento final por ser demasiado corto.
Esta es la clase:
public class Agenda {
    private Tarea[] vectorTarea;

    public Agenda() {
        vectorTarea = new Tarea[0];
    }
    private int posiciónInserción(Tarea tarea) {
        Fecha fecha = tarea.getFecha();
        for (int i=0; i<vectorTarea.length;i++) {
            Fecha fecha2 = vectorTarea[i].getFecha();
            if (fecha.compareTo(fecha2)<0){
                return i;
            }
        }
        return vectorTarea.length;
    }
    public void añadir(Tarea tarea) {
        //Crea un vectorTarea auxiliar
        Tarea[] vectorAuxiliar = vectorTarea;
        int pos = posiciónInserción(tarea);
        for (int i=0;i<vectorTarea.length+1;i++){
            if (i==pos) {
                vectorTarea[i] = tarea;
            }else if (i<pos){
                vectorTarea[i] = vectorAuxiliar[i];
            }else {
                vectorTarea[i] = vectorAuxiliar[i-1];
            }
        }
    }
}


Y porque no creas otro vector, de tamaño tarea+1, copias los elementos, y luego devuelves ese vector?? y de paso , lo igualas a vector tareas???

Es verdad, muchas gracias.

En java los array no son dimensionables. Si quieres aumentarle el tamaño reasígnalo a uno más grande, copia todos los elementos y devuélvelo O, usa una estructura diferente (arraylist por ejemplo).

No. Para eso existen las listas.

Una vez instanciado, no se puede. Te sugiero usar un ArrayList que te permite ir agregando:
    ArrayList<Tarea> lista= new ArrayList<Tarea>();

private void agregar(Tarea t){
    lista.add(t);
}

